# Typing text with a button in createJS on animateCC

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

I start in CreateJS..
My code doesn't work and I need help.

I wish to realize a virtual keyboard. The goal is to enter the correct 4-digit code, using the different buttons (from 0 to 9). The C key deletes the digits.

How to make a button that displays text on the click?

Thanks a lot for your help !
Matt

```
//Référence du scénario
_this = this;

//Curseur souris
stage.enableMouseOver();

//Gestion du touché sur tablette/mobile
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);

//Variables
var passKey = "1234";
var displayText;
var displayAccessText;

function numDisplay(num) {
    if (displayText.length < 5)
    {
        displayAccessText="";
        displayText +=num;
        displayNum.text = displayText;
        displayAccess.text= displayAccessText;
    }
}


_this.key1.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum1);
_this.key2.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum2);
_this.key3.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum3);
_this.key4.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum4);
_this.key5.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum5);
_this.key6.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum6);
_this.key7.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum7);
_this.key8.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum8);
_this.key9.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum9);
_this.key0.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknum0);
_this.keycancel.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknumc);
_this.keyenter.addEventListener("mousedown", clicknumenter);


function clicknum1() {
numDisplay("1");
}

function clicknum2() {
numDisplay("2");
}

function clicknum3() {
numDisplay("3");
}

function clicknum4() {
numDisplay("4");
}

function clicknum5() {
numDisplay("5");
}

function clicknum6() {
numDisplay("6");
}

function clicknum7() {
numDisplay("7");
}

function clicknum8() {
numDisplay("8");
}

function clicknum9() {
numDisplay("9");
}

function clicknum0() {
numDisplay("0");
}

function clicknumc() {
displayText = "";
displayNum.text= displayText;   
}

function clicknumenter() {
    if (displayText==passKey) {
        displayText="";
        displayAccess.text="TRUE";
    }
    else {
        displayText="";
        displayAccessText="FALSE";
        displayAccess.text=displayAccessText;
        displayNum.text = displayText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's good!

I forget to initialized a variable... and trying to add to an uninitialized variable (displayText).

Thanks!